# How can write event for textbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I wrote a program in python 3.6.2 by tkinter,i wrote bellow code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input())
buttonCommit.pack()
mainloop()
```

i want when press Enter key in textbox print "you press Enter in textbox".
How can i write event ?

Comment: Have you done any research? Binding to events is very fundamental, and is covered in just about every tkinter tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()

def alertme(*args):
    messagebox.showinfo("Message", "you press Enter in textbox")

def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()

textBox.bind("<Return>", alertme) #this line calls alertme function whenever you press Enter key

buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input())
buttonCommit.pack()
mainloop()
```

Now It will work only inside that Text Box...

Comment: This will print no matter which widget the cursor is in. Since this program only has one input widget  the point is moot, but for a program that has more than one input widget this is not a good solution. You shouldn't be binding to `root`.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  how fix it?

Comment: bind to the text widget